# In bash, how to sort while ignoring a prefix?

Tags: shell, sorting, command-line, prefix

I know the sort command can be made to use only some of the information on each input line as the sort key, e.g. using `sort -k 2` to skip the initial sequence of characters up to a whitespace; and I know I can use a different field delimiter with `-t`.

Suppose, though, that I want to sort input while ignoring the first few characters - which are not fixed. For example, this:

```
bar10
baz12
foo1
gaa11
quu2
```

should become, using only the 4th character and onwards:

```
foo1
bar10
gaa11
baz12
quu2
```

Of course I can do this with a more involved scripting language, like awk (e.g. [this way](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal)). But is there something simpler I could do instead?

Comment: @Lynn: Hmm, Yeah, I guess doing both post- and pre-processing could work, see my answer below. I'd like to avoid it if possible though.

Comment: Note that the field denotation for `sort` can have the form `-k M.N`, in which case M is the field number and N is the offset in characters inside the field. If you want to use field 2, but starting with the forth character, it would be `-k 2.4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it's just: `sort -k1.4`

---

The syntax understood by `sort` is rather drily explained in the standard: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html

(But it does provide a few examples.)

It's worth remembering that `locale` settings affect output ordering.

Comment: you can get potentially unexpected behaviour if you do things like `-t ' ' -k1.4,1` and the first field is shorter than 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming your prefix has no spaces, you could write:

```
prefix_length=3
sed -r 's/^(.{'$prefix_length'})/\1 /;' | \
sort -k 2 | \
sed -r 's/^(.{'$prefix_length'}) /\1/;'
```

What this does:

- The first `sed` command inserts a space character after your (non-fixed) prefix
- Then we sort, using a space as the field delimiter and the second field as the key
- The second `sed` command removes the inserted space character

Comment: Otherwise known as [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) You can also use a `\t` with a pipe line this: `sed -E 's/(^.{3}(.*))/\2\t\1/' file | sort | sed 's/^[^\t]*\t//'`

Comment: since you are assuming there are no spaces in the prefix (otherwise `-k2` fails), you can just do: `prefix=3; sed "s/./& /$prefix" inputfile | sort -k2 | sed 's/ //' >outputfile`